# How to show balloon under the marker (BalloonItemizedOverlay)?

Tags: android, google-maps, balloon

I use BalloonItemizedOverlay.
How to show balloon under the marker? (It is from the center of a marker by default.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using [this one](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons) you have the method

```
public void setBalloonBottomOffset(int pixels)
```

*Set the horizontal distance between the marker and the bottom of the information balloon. The default is 0 which works well for center bounded markers. If your marker is center-bottom bounded, call this before adding overlay items to ensure the balloon hovers exactly above the marker.*

So, if you have a marker that has the usual V at the bottom, defining the point where it touches the map, you need to set an offset of half it's height BEFORE you add it to the overlays.

Example:

```
 -----    ^
|     |   |
|     |  20 px  of height, you need to do marker.setBalloonBottomOffset(-10)
 -- --    |
   V      v
```